# In Gentoo, what is the difference between amd64, ~amd64 and ~amd64-linux?

Tags: gentoo, chrome, dependencies

When I run `equery depgraph www-client/chromium-10.0.648.151`, not all dependencies are available. Some shows `M[package.mask]`, while some other shows `[missing keyword]`. My `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS` is `~amd64-linux`, according to `emerge --info`. I experimented with different `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS` (as an environmental variable passed to `eqeury`), and all have different missing dependencies. Among all possible combinations, only with `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS='amd64 ~amd64 ~amd64-linux'` all dependencies can be satisfied at once.

**Here are my questions:**

1. Is `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS='amd64 ~amd64 ~amd64-linux'` a valid configuration?
2. I learned from the documentation that `amd64` mean stable, and  `~amd64` means unstable. What about `~amd64-linux`?
3. If I select `~amd64`, `equery` wouldn't use the packages available only to  `amd64`, resulting in missing dependencies. Is this expected? If so, should unstable testers use at least `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS='amd64 ~amd64'` instead of `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS='~amd64'`?
4. Does the order of the keywords matter?

---

Additional info: I installed Gentoo Prefix following [this guide](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/bootstrap-solaris.xml). By default, 
`$EPREFIX/etc/make.profile` is a symlink to `$EPREFIX/usr/portage/profiles/prefix/linux/amd64` and contains a `make.defaults` that has `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="-amd64 ~amd64-linux"`. Neither `$EPREFIX/etc/make.conf` nor `$EPREFIX/etc/make.globals` has `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS` configured. According to `eselect profile list`, no profile is selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. Is ACCEPT_KEYWORDS='amd64 ~amd64 ~amd64-linux' a valid configuration?**

From man make.conf:

> ACCEPT_KEYWORDS = [space delimited list of KEYWORDS]

So `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS='amd64 ~amd64 ~amd64-linux'` is a valid combination.

**2. What about ~amd64-linux?**

`amd64-linux` is a Prefix thing. I don't know much about Prefix, but I can see `amd64-linux` in the list of valid keywords at `/usr/portage/profiles/arch.list`, in the section named "Prefix keywords". `~amd64-linux` is just the testing counterpart of `amd64-linux`.

**3. `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS='amd64 ~amd64'` vs just `~amd64`**

If you have `~amd64` in your `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS`, portage will use all the latest ebuilds, which often contains a lot of unstable stuff. I think that's why missing dependencies are to be expected. For example, that can happen if you want to install `software-a`, and the latest one in the testing branch is `software-a-2.3.4`, which requires `library-b-5.6.7`, which doesn't have an ebuild yet. Regarding `amd64 ~amd64` and just `~amd64`, they are the same, really, because if your architecture is amd64 you will have `amd64` in `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS`, no matter what.

**4. Does the order of the keywords matter?**

No, because it's just a matter of whether your `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS` variable contains a certain keyword or not. It's like a set (unordered).

Having used Gentoo for a while, I still don't have the dare to put `~amd64` in my `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS`. It's so unstable it's really not recommended, setting it up for the first time guarantees a lot of breakage.

Comment: thanks for the very clear explanation. in my case, I still *had* to put in ~amd64 to get the latest `xtables-addons`. but since my Gentoo box serves as a pure firewall, I'm not really concerned of other packages' stability :)

Comment: @pepoluan If `~amd64` is just to have `xtables-addons` then you should put it in `/etc/portage/package.keywords` or `/etc/portage/package.accept_keywords` instead of using the unstable testing branch. For more information refer to `man portage`, or ask here in a different question.

Comment: gosh, you're right >.< ... I apologize, it seems my n00bness shines through :P ... anyways, I'm not the original poster, just a wayward commenter :)

Comment: @pepoluan Glad I was of help. Everybody is a noob at some point :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I don't understand why but the default keyword is `~amd64-linux` (with `amd64` explicitly removed). So far it's running well =)

Answer (score 3):

The ACCEPT_KEYWORDS environment variable is for allowing "all" not-yet-marked stable packages/versions for the current architecture to be built.

The ~ in front of an arch means unstable (not "completely" tested).

The often better approach is to use /etc/portage/package.keywords and list the package in there with the ~amd64 keyword if you really need the latest build.

By the way: amd64 firewall, isn't that how wikipedia defines overkill?

1. Yes
2. Never heard of "~amd64-linux", but the ~ means "unstable".
3. No, it is not expected that "~amd64" excludes "amd64".
4. No.